# Can I use a Calendar date selector when using custom SQL query parameters that use Unix timestamps?

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I'm using a custom SQL query and parameters for start and end date ranges in a workbook that I've created. Currently the dashboard users need to enter a unix timestamp for the start and end parameters.

Instead of using the timestamp, I want someone using the dashboard to be able to choose a date using a date-selector, and I want the date that they selected to be converted into a unix timestamp (ex: 8/1/2018 = 1533081600) that is used as an SQL query parameter.

Does anyone know if this is possible with Tableau?

Comment: didn't get your requirement.. can you add more data how exactly you need in tableau

Comment: I want someone using the dashboard to be able to choose a date using a date-selector, and I want the date that they selected to be converted into a unix timestamp (ex: 8/1/2018 = 1533081600) that is used as an SQL query parameter.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and make your explanation part of it?

Comment: What db platform are you using? Since you are using custom sql, have you sql make the conversion from date string to Unix timestamp.

Comment: So you need to convert the normal date to unix date and attach in where clause of the query, is it correct?

Comment: @SamM I think this may be what I end up needing to do

Comment: @Siva Yes, this is correct. I'd ideally like a sort of date selector that's human readable that converts to a unix timestamp that is then used as custom SQL query parameters.